# Unable to connect Bigquery on PowerBi Application

Tags: google-bigquery, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

When I connect to my BigQuery on PowerBI Desktop and try to pull data from one of the largest projects(having over 200 datasets with 30,000 date partitioned tables) under Bigquery, I get the error below.

[image]

Used features: Odbc.DataSource/Microsoft ODBC
Driver for Google BigQuery/2.4.0.1002/BigQuery

I tried clearing the cache in powerbi application folder(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Power BI Desktop\Cache) and it doesn’t work for me.

Could you please help me with this.

Comment: Can you please share BigQuery error logs, if any?

Comment: Thank you for the response. we see the issue on the powerbi application. I'm relatively new to it. could you help me on identifying the error logs.

Comment: Inside your GCP project, please go to Cloud Logging >>  Logs Explorer. At the top right there is a clock like option, please click on that and enter the custom time range around the time you got the PowerBI error. Verify that “Refine Scope” (at the top) is chosen as “Scope by project”.  Run this query: resource.type="bigquery_resource" severity=ERROR . You can download the logs from the Actions menu in Query results.

Comment: Would that error be related to powerbi or because of BigQuery application?

Comment: That is what I intend to check, that if there is any error on BigQuery side or the issue is occurring on PowerBI side alone.